# Displaying a repeat within a repeat in VF page

Tags: apex, visualforce

Based on my earlier [question](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/3471/how-do-i-define-a-list-to-hold-a-summary-data-and-then-drill-down-further) i had built up a wrapper class to display in the format below.

```
  Area            Allocated   Currently available
 - New York       20              15
    Vendor1       10              10
    Vendor2       10              5

 - Philadelphia   10              8
    Vendor1       5               5
    Vendor2       5               3

public class HDDevicesbyArea
    {
        public string HD_Area{get;set;}
        public double HD_Current {get;set;}
        public string HD_Allocated {get; set;}
        List<HDDevicesbyVendor> ListHDDevicesbyVendor {get; set;}
        public HDDevicesbyArea ( string HD_Area_v, string allocated_v, List<HDDevicesbyVendor> ListHDDevicesbyVendor_v )
        {
         // constructor code
        }
```

How should i have my VF page to set show the inner list also show in the same columns?
I have a Lsit of class HDDevicesArea which i would repeat in VF page. I also have List ListHDDevicesbyVendor  within the class HDDevicesbyArea

I need to show ListHDDevicesbyVendor  using the same columns as HDDevicesbyArea

```
<apex:pageBlock id="theResultBlock" >
    <apex:pageBlockSection id="ResultSection" columns="1" >
     <table width="100%" cellpadding ="1" cellspacing = "1">
        <tr>
            <th>Area / Vendor</th>
            <th>Allocation</th>
            <th>Current</th>

        </tr>
              <apex:repeat value="{!HDDevicesbyArea}" var="HD" id="theRepeat">
        <tr>
              <td><apex:outputText value= "{!HD.HD_Vendor"} /></td>
              <td><apex:outputText value= "{!HD.HD_Current"}</td>
              <td><apex:outputText value= "{!HD.HD_Allocated"}</td>
            </tr>
            </apex:repeat>
        </table>
    </apex:pageBlockSection>
 </apex:pageBlock>
```

Thanks in Advance

Comment: Hi Prady, it'd be easier to give an accurate solution if you show what your VF looks like already, otherwise a suggested solution may not fit with what you have.

Comment: @LaceySnr i have updated the VF page which i have till now. I could use <apex:DataTable> instead of just the HTML table but was not sure on how i can achived showing the vendors also in the same columns

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'd avoid using datatable as per your comments, as its quite difficult to do anything other than iterate a common set of data and output a column per property.  I think this is simply a matter of iterating the inner list and generating its own HTML table rows.  E.g.

```
<apex:repeat value="{!HDDevicesbyArea}" var="HD" id="theRepeat">
  <tr>
     <td><apex:outputText value= "{!HD.HD_Area"} /></td>
     <td><apex:outputText value= "{!HD.HD_Current"}</td>
     <td><apex:outputText value= "{!HD.HD_Allocated"}</td>
  </tr>

  <apex:repeat value="{!HD.ListHDDevicesbyVendor}" var="dev">
    <tr>
     <td><apex:outputText value= "{!dev.HD_Vendor}" /></td>
     <td><apex:outputText value= "{!dev.HD_Current"}</td>
     <td><apex:outputText value= "{!dev.HD_Allocated"}</td>
    </tr>
  </apex:repeat>
</apex:repeat>
```

That way the first row in the repeat contains the area and current/allocated, and the following rows contain the vendor and the current/allocated.

Comment: could you please add the controller for this page ?

Comment: I don't have a controller - this is based on the OP question, I've simply altered their markup.

Comment: wouldn't this give the error: "Object type not accessible. Please check permissions and make sure the object is not in development mode: SOQL statements cannot query aggregate relationships more than 1 level away from the root entity object."? - edit: oh right, the OP's controller will allow nested <apex:repeat> tags

Answer (score 1):

I would imagine two structures, one for traversing and one for looking up to:

```
Map <string, HDDevicesbyArea> allocationMap
```

And

```
List <string> keyNames
```

In the List keep adding the list of values as in the hierarchy, eg {NewYork, NYVendor1, NYVendor2, Philadelphia, PHVendor 1, PHVendor2}

In your apex:repeat iterate over this flat list,

However to render fetch details from the map
allocationMap[var]

```
<apex:repeat value="{!keyNames}"  var="keyName">
 <td><apex:outputText value= "{!allocationMap[keyName].HD_Vendor"} /></td>
 <td><apex:outputText value= "{!allocationMap[keyName].HD_Current"}</td>
 <td><apex:outputText value= "{!allocationMap[keyName].HD_Allocated"}</td>
</apex:repeat>
```

In this way you traverse over a flat list but lookup to the Map for rendering